# Just Inserting Blank array() inside in mysql error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to store image name only inside mysql table but issue is that it's uploading blank array and giving **error**

> array to string conversion.

```
if(isset($_POST['prd_submit']) && isset($_FILES['prd_image'])){
// Define Input Variables
    $name = user_input($_POST['prd_name']);
    $detail =  user_input($_POST['prd_detail']);
    $image = $_FILES['prd_image'];
    $buy_link = user_input($_POST['prd_link']);
    $price = user_input($_POST['prd_price']);
    $category = $_POST['prd_category'];
    $country = $_POST['prd_country'];
    // Control Error Inputs
    if(empty($name)){
        $name_err = "Name is missing";
    }
    if(empty($detail)){
        $detail_err = "Detail is missing";
    }
    if(empty($price)){
        $price_err = "Price is missing";
    }
    if(empty($buy_link)){
        $buy_link_err = "Link is missing";
    }
    // File Upload Function
    $OutFiles = array();
    foreach($image as $Index=>$Items){
        foreach($Items as $Key=>$Item){
            $OutFiles[$Key][$Index] = $Item;
        }
    }
    if($OutFiles[0]['error']){
        $image_err = $Errors[$OutFiles[0]['error']];
    }else{
        foreach($OutFiles as $Index=>$File){
            $UploadDir = $DocRoot.'/upload/';
            $imageName = $File['name'];
            //GETTING FILE EXTENTION
            $file_ext = explode('.',$imageName);
            $file_ext = $file_ext[count($file_ext)-1];
            //FILE NAME
            $filename = (rand()).'-'.(time()).'.'.$file_ext;
            //FILE EXTENTION ERROR
            if($file_ext != "jpg" && $file_ext != "png" && $file_ext != "jpeg" && $file_ext != "gif"){
                $error = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
            }elseif(move_uploaded_file($File['tmp_name'],$UploadDir.$filename)){
                $OutFiles[$Index]['name'] = $filename;
                $uploadok++;
            }elseif($uploadok == 0){
                $error = "Sorry File is Not Upload";
            }else{
                $uploadok--;
                $error = "Sorry File is Not Upload";
            }
        }
    }
    // Insert DB
    if($name_err == '' && $detail_err == '' && $image_err == '' && $price_err == '' && $buy_link_err == ''){            
        $Code = 0;
        try{
            $insert_data = ("INSERT INTO product (name,country,detail,image,price,buy_link,category,date_posted) VALUES ('$name','$country','$detail','$image','$price','$buy_link','$category','$date')");
            $insert_data = $conn->query($insert_data);
        }catch(PDOException $E){            
            $Code = $E->getCode();
        }
        if($Code == 0){
            $error =  "<div class='alert alert-success'>Your Product Registration Request Has Submitted!</div>";
        }elseif($Code == 23000){
            $error =  "<div class='alert alert-info'>Duplicate Entry</div>";
        }else{
            $error = "Unabel to enter data";
        }
    }
```

To much confuse what thing i'm doing wrong in it and if implode array but how i can implode i just need name only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$image` To `$filename` in your **INSERT** query.

Because, `$image = $_FILES['prd_image'];` is an array and you wanted to store the file name which is just uploaded to `upload` folder. So, use `$filename` which is uploaded using `elseif(move_uploaded_file($File['tmp_name'],$UploadDir.$filename)){`

**Query**

```
$insert_data = "INSERT INTO product (name,country,detail,image,price,buy_link,category,date_posted) VALUES ('$name','$country','$detail','$filename','$price','$buy_link','$category','$date')";
```

**Uploading Multiple File** : Move your **INSERT** Query inside `foreach`. It will insert into table on every successful upload.

```
foreach ($OutFiles as $Index => $File) {
  $UploadDir = $DocRoot . '/upload/';
  $imageName = $File['name'];
  //GETTING FILE EXTENTION
  $file_ext = explode('.', $imageName);
  $file_ext = $file_ext[count($file_ext) - 1];
  //FILE NAME
  $filename = (rand()) . '-' . (time()) . '.' . $file_ext;
  //FILE EXTENTION ERROR
  if ($file_ext != "jpg" && $file_ext != "png" && $file_ext != "jpeg" && $file_ext != "gif") {
    $error = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  } elseif (move_uploaded_file($File['tmp_name'], $UploadDir . $filename)) {
    $OutFiles[$Index]['name'] = $filename;
    $insert_data = "INSERT INTO product (name,country,detail,image,price,buy_link,category,date_posted) VALUES ('$name','$country','$detail','$filename','$price','$buy_link','$category','$date')";
    $insert_data = $conn->query($insert_data);
    $uploadok++;
  } elseif ($uploadok == 0) {
    $error = "Sorry File is Not Upload";
  } else {
    $uploadok--;
    $error = "Sorry File is Not Upload";
  }
}
```

And, remove `try/catch` from below as now it's **INSERTING** on every **UPLOAD**.

Comment: it's update file name inside database but only one image name as i have uploaded upto 10

Comment: I didn't get it. Please elaborate once @MuhammadHamzaNisar

Comment: it is updating now only one image name. But i'm uploading multiple image and it's inserting only one image name inside database

Comment: Wait for 1-2 minutes. That's what I asked in comment. @MuhammadHamzaNisar

Comment: i couldn't get you

Comment: thanks for your i convert filename to an array and then implode this list with comma